# select all forms except one without specific action using css

Tags: html, css

I need to write a css rule for all forms except for the form with a specific action,

Currently I have the below css, for all #NavMenu, I am hiding them, but for search, I want to show them.

```
form #NavMenu{
display:none;
}
form[action*='Search'] #NavMenu{
display:block;
}
```

Is there a way where I can specify all forms but not this, like

```
form:not(form[action*='search']) #NavMenu{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: `form:not([action*='search'])`

Comment: thanks, can you post this as answer so that i can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selector should be like below

`form:not([action*='search'])` where the form will search if it has the attribute